# A cadeia de caracteres especificada não está no formato necessário para um endereço de email

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Estou fazendo uma rotina e não estou tendo sucesso estou tendo esse erro e  no web.config deixei assim

```
  <system.net >
<mailSettings>
  <smtp from="xxx@gmail.com">
    <network host="smtp.gmail.com" password="******" port="587" userName="testesolers"  enableSsl="true"/>
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

E na Aplicação a chamada  foi feita desta forma:

```
Dim client = New SmtpClient()
Return client.SendMailAsync("Mensagem Automática", message.Destination.ToString(), message.Subject.ToString(), message.Body.ToString())
```

Onde estou errando ?

Comment: Qual o email de destino que você está usando? Pode ser ele o problema.

Comment: Qual o conteúdo de `message.Destination`?

Comment: estou usando o meu próprio gmail como destino